# Ansible role does not add missing defaults

Tags: ansible

If I add any part of a var dict in the playbook...it won't fill in the rest of the dict from the role defaults. Is that normal? It's very confusing.

Playbook snippet:

```
- role: nvm
    nvm:
      node_version: '6.11.0'
```

All of `defaults/main.yml`

```
---
nvm:
  user: "{{ ansible_user_id | default('goats') }}"
  version: v0.4.0

  node_version: '0.10'
```

gets ignored, and the `nvm` object only contains `node_version`

Am I being unreasonable to expect it would have added the missing values, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of ansible when you define the same variable is to replace it, with precedence defined in "[Variable Precedence: Where Should I Put A Variable?](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)"

You can change this behavior by setting the configuration [`hash_behaviour`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#hash-behaviour) to `merge`

Comment: That looked good. I set `hash_behavior = merge` in my ansible.cfg and it doesn't seem to be merging though.

Comment: Humm, maybe it's not working for defaults and role params...

Comment: This may be off-topic, but I can't even locate `hash_behavior` in the https://github.com/ansible/ansible codebase to see if it should. Only tests.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it's `hash_behavio**u**r`